# What does this schematic symbol mean (transistor with two emitters)?

Tags: transistors, schematics, semiconductors, symbol

Basically the question is, what it is?

Are those two emitters (meaning that part of semiconductor heavily doped)?

[image]

Comment: There are multi emitter transistors too but their schematic symbol looks different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an IGBT. It has one collector and one emitter, but sometimes people draw an arrow on the collector too, perhaps because in truth the "collector" of an N-type IGBT is the emitter of an internal PNP BJT. (and no one makes P-type IGBTs, as far as I know, other than one from Toshiba that's no longer manufactured.)

The more common symbol for an IGBT is closer to this:

[image]

([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IGBT_symbol.svg))

You can think of an IGBT as a hybrid between a BJT and a MOSFET, with an insulated gate but the output characteristics of a bipolar device. This is what the symbol attempts to suggest: the gate separated from the channel as in a MOSFET, but the 45°-angled collector and emitter with an arrow on one as in a BJT.

Comment: What does what unconnected pin represent?

Comment: @Qeeet Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry, I've forggot to specify. What is the unconnected "wire" on the symbol I posted (between emitter and collector)?

Comment: @Qeeet Oh! I'm not sure what that's meant to represent. The older symbols for IGBTs have it, while the ones you see today generally don't.

Comment: it seems it represents the n- region of the device, according to https://www.electrical4u.com/insulated-gate-bipolar-transistor-igbt/
figure: https://www.electrical4u.com/images/2017/february/1487085541.PNG?ezimgfmt=rs:568x364/rscb38/ng:webp/ngcb38

Comment: @Hearth I dont know anything about IGTBS what you mean by :"the output characteristics of a bipolar device"?

Comment: @MissMulan They have a saturation voltage instead of an Rdson, they don't have a body diode, that sort of thing.